# HTC Vive USB Audio not detected

Tags: usb, sound, alsa

I recently picked up an HTC Vive, which is working (overall) pretty well, except for sound. Pulseaudio refuses to detect the device as a valid sound output:

[image]

However, the audio input is detected and actually works:

[image]

Unfortunately, the lack of speakers makes things difficult to say the least.

`aplay -l` returns the following output, suggesting a connection is detected:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC298 Analog [ALC298 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Do [Corsair VOID Wireless Gaming Do], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Vive [HTC Vive], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

However, `aplay -D plughw:2,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav` returns a very odd output:

```
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

I've made sure all of the connectors are securely plugged in, so this appears to be a software issue.

My only hint so far is `pulseaudio` outputting the following lines in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Dec  3 16:12:54 greywolf pulseaudio[2547]: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to load mixer: Invalid argument
Dec  3 16:12:54 greywolf pulseaudio[2547]: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Unable to load mixer: Invalid argument
```

What can I do to solve this issue?